# Matrix with its name on it, of huge size

Tags: matrices

How can I replace the original matrix `[L]` which is of normal size with a huge one, like this figure shows (the red result is what I want):

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_{1} \\
\delta_{2} \\
\vdots \\
\delta_{M} \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\qquad\qquad \\
\\
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\Huge $L$} \\
\\
\end{bmatrix}_{M\times M}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{1} \\
v_{2} \\
\vdots \\
v_{M} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @C.Wang I've improved the answer in my edit.

Answer (score 12):

If you want the same size of the brackets, use a `\vphantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_{1} \\
\delta_{2} \\
\vdots \\
\delta_{M} \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\left[
\vphantom{%
  \begin{matrix}
  v_{1} \\
  v_{2} \\
  \vdots \\
  v_{M} \\
  \end{matrix}%
}
\quad\begin{gathered}\text{\Huge $L$}\end{gathered}\quad
\right]_{M\times M}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{1} \\
v_{2} \\
\vdots \\
v_{M} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity (and excuse my ignorance), but why do you switch to text mode before issuing `\Huge`, only to re-enter math mode with `$L$`?

Comment: @SeanAllred `\Huge` in math mode is illegal.

Comment: `\includegraphics{simpler-than-expected}`

Answer (score 3):

This way?

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, textwidth = 16cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{graphics}

    \begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{bmatrix}
    δ_1\\δ_{2} \\ \vdots \\ δ_M
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \vphantom{\begin{matrix} δ_1 &   & δ_M \\δ_{2} \\ \vdots \\ δ_M \end{matrix}}\scalebox{2.5}{\enspace$ L $\enspace}
    \end{bmatrix}_{M× M}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1\\v_{2} \\ \vdots \\ v_M
    \end{bmatrix} ,
    \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Concisely, with stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\tmp}{\Huge $L$}
\begin{equation}
\left[\addstackgap{\Centerstack{\delta_1 \delta_2 {\vdots} \delta_M}}\right]
=
\left[\addstackgap[2.5\baselineskip]{\smash{~~~~~~\raisebox{-.3\ht\tmpcontent}{\tmp}~~~~~~}}\right]_{M\times M}
\left[\addstackgap{\Centerstack{v_1 v_2 {\vdots} v_M}}\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]